# Step Definition File Errors

Tags: c#, specflow

I working on a simple step definition file using Specflow for a page that test okay using Nunit. Can some explain the error shown in the attachment ? I am able to do the same in the Unit test file.

[image: Screen shot for error]

Step definition:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TedsChallenge.step_definition
{
    [Binding]
    public class RestaurantNameSteps
    {

        private static IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //public RestaurantNameSteps(IWebDriver driver)
        //{
        //    driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //    //this.driver = driver;
        //    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        //}

        YelpHomepage yelpHomepage = new YelpHomepage(driver);

        [Given(@"Navigated to Yelp site")]
        public void GivenNavigatedToYelpSite()
        {

            yelpHomepage.NavigateToYelp();
        }

        [When(@"Search for a restaurant")]
        public void WhenSearchForARestaurant()
        {
            yelpHomepage.SendSearchString("Teds Montana Grill", "Denver, CO");

            //_driver.Close();
        }

        [Then(@"Display and verify the name")]
        public void ThenDisplayAndVerifyTheName()
        {
            string nameofRes = yelpHomepage.GetNameofRestuarant();
            Console.WriteLine(nameofRes);
            //Verify the name of the restaurant on the page
```

Comment: I uploaded the image. Not sure if you can see it. I cannot.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `private static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`?

Comment: Yes, that line did resolve the issue.

Comment: I was able to edit the question and get the screenshot displaying. That was kind of wonky.